# How do you use collection_select in the following (easy) situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have these 2 models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :contact, :name

  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many :books

end

class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :checkin, :checkout, :notes, :person, :book

end
```

In registers/_form.html.erb I want to use f.collection_select where I can select a Person's name from a list. The purpose of the Register model is to record a history of checkouts.

This is my first time trying to use collection_select and I can't wrap my head around it with the examples I have read on stackoverflow and google. Maybe I don't have all that is needed in the models?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are errors in your model with regards to associations. The correct associations should be:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :registers, :inverse_of => :person
end

class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :person, :inverse_of => :registers
end
```

Then in your `registers/_form.html.erb` you have to have something like the following:

```
<%= form_for :register do |f| %>
   <% # ... input elements for the rest of the Register model %>

   <%= f.collection_select :person_id, Person.all, :id, :name %>

   <% # ... input elements for the rest of the Register model %>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. When I paste those lines into my code I get ``undefined method `person_id' for #<Register:0x007f9cb9528c00>`` on the `http://localhost:3000/registers/new` page. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your column called `person_id` on the table `registers`? How is it called?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I am a noob. Do you mean that I need a foreign key called person_id in the register table?

Comment: Yes. This is what I mean. You need a column with name `person_id` on table `registers`.

Comment: I added that person_id to the migration for the Register table and ran rake db:migrate:redo. I am still getting an ```undefined method `person_id' for #<Register:0x007f9cb90f9b48>```. What am I missing?

Comment: I figured it out the undefined method problem. I had to drop the database and then create it again. Thanks. Now I will test it a bit more.